# Can't install angular2-datatable in VS2015 project with npm

Tags: angular, npm

I'm developing an angular 2 web app with asp.net 5. I want to install angular2-datatable with npm to create a table. I've added the following dependency to my package.json file:

```
"angular2-datatable": "^0.4.2"
```

After I save the file the dependency doesn't get installed. On the opposite I get the following result:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs;%PATH%;.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD" install
> angular2-datatable@0.4.2 postinstall C:\hmr9sw\RWD\src\RWD\node_modules\angular2-datatable
> cd src && typings install
undefined:1
{
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at exports.parse (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\rc\lib\utils.js:15:17)
    at addConfigFile (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\rc\index.js:31:20)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\rc\index.js:45:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\typings-core\dist\utils\rc.js:11:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
npm WARN rwd@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN rwd@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN rwd@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-datatable@0.4.2 postinstall: `cd src && typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-datatable@0.4.2 postinstall script 'cd src && typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-datatable package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cd src && typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-datatable
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-datatable
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\hmr9sw\RWD\src\RWD\npm-debug.log
```

As you can see my npm version is 3.9.5 and my node version is 6.2.1 (therefore they are updated). If I run npm through cmd I get the same result.

Comment: Possibly a broken package, I guess?

Comment: yes but my colleagues can install it by doing the same thing that I do

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, were you able to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using angular2-data-table (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-data-table). It gets installed without any errors and the features are really good.